# Assembly Instruction interpretation

Tags: c, assembly, gdb

I see this instruction:

```
*0x804a1a0(,%eax,4)
```

I got the value at 0x804a1a0 and added the value of $eax*4, but that's not where the code jumped to.  I did the same using the value 0x804a1a0 itself plus $eax*4 and it points elsewhere.  How do I interpret the instruction above?

Comment: maybe *(0x804a1a0+eax*4) ? looks like a switch jump table to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The short anwser:

You say:

> I got the value at 0x804a1a0 and added the value of $eax*4

This is wrong.

> I did the same using the value 0x804a1a0 itself plus $eax*4

This is also wrong.

What you want is to compute `0x804a1a0 + eax*4` first, and then look at the value at that memory location.

### The long answer:

The code you provided is not a full instruction, rather an operand to a move/jump/call instruction in *AT&T* syntax. More specifically, it's called an *effective address*. Basically this is a form of *indirect addressing*, which means the memory at the location given by the operand will be used.

The *AT&T* syntax of an effective address is:

```
DISP(BASE,INDEX,SCALE)
```

which should be interpreted as:

```
BASE + INDEX*SCALE + DISP
```

In your case,

```
0x804a1a0(,%eax,4)
```

is really:

```
%eax*4 + 0x804a1a0
```

Now for the `*`, according to http://wiki.osdev.org/Opcode_syntax:

> Relative Addressing: Used by default in all jump and call instructions.
>
> To use absolute addressing, the operand must be prefixed with an asterisk (*).

Also, from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addressing_mode:

> The effective address for an absolute instruction address is the address parameter itself with no modifications.

So the final address is actually the location pointed to by `eax*4 + 0x804a1a0`.

If I had to guess, I'd say it's probably a jump/switch table at offset `0x804a1a0`. In other words, the code does not execute at offset `eax*4 + 0x804a1a0`, rather it reads the address stored at that location, and jumps to that (hence it's an *indirect jump*).

**Side rant**: I really hate *AT&T* syntax. If you're new to assembly, you might prefer Intel syntax. I think it's far more readable. Your code in Intel syntax would probably be:

```
jmp dword ptr [0x804a1a0 + eax*4]
```

assuming the instruction is a jump.